# Simple Lagrange Multiplier question

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

*EDIT: Original question was linear. I have changed the problem to be quadratic instead, replacing each $x_i$ with $x_i^2$, but the difficulty remains the same.*

I am extremely rusty with Lagrange multiplier optimization, and as a refresher I was looking at the following problem, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why I cannot solve this.

I am trying to maximise: $$f(x_1, ..., x_n) = \sum^n_{i=1} x_i^2 c_i$$ subject to the constraint that $$\sum^n_{i=1} x_i^2 = 1$$

It is intuitively clear that the solution should be $|x_j| = 1$ for whatever $c_j$ is maximal, and $x_j = 0$ otherwise.

However attempting to show this using Lagragian multipliers, I consider $$\sum^n_{i=1}x_i^2 c_i - \lambda \left[1 - \sum^n_{i=1} x_i^2 \right]$$

The partial derivative with respect to $x_j$ yields $$2 x_j c_j + 2 x_j \lambda = 0$$

Then we must have that either $x_j = 0$ or $\lambda = -c_j$

The partial derivative with respect to $\lambda$ yields $$\sum^n_{i=1} x_i^2 = 1$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Specifically, which $j \in [n]$ do we let $\lambda = -c_j$?

EDIT 2:
Staring at the problem longer, I believe I figured out how to proceed, but I would appreciate if someone could let me know if the approach is valid/best. Starting from $j=1, ..., n$, I simply let $\lambda = - c_j$ which forces $x_k = 0$ for $k \neq j$.

Hence: $$\sum^n_{i=1}x_i^2 c_i - \lambda \left[1 - \sum^n_{i=1} x_i^2 \right] = x_j^2 c_j - x_j^2 c_j + c_j = c_j$$

Across all $j = 1, ..., n$, it is clear that we must choose $\lambda = -c_m$ where $c_m$ is maximal. Thus $x_k = 0$ for $k \neq m$, and thus $|x_m| = 1$.

Comment: $f$ doesn't have a maximum subject to that constraint.  You need additional constraints such as $x_i\ge 0$ for all $x_i$ to maximize this function.

Comment: It does not work because the target function and the restraint are linear in in $x_j$. Try a function $f$ that is quadratic, and you will get see how it works.

Comment: No. What you found is ok.  Your function $y=c_1x_1+...+c_nx_n$ draws a plane in infinite space. It has no maximum or minumum even together with the "the subject to condition": Intersection of two subplanes is a subplane... So the method gave no solution. This is my thoughts. I hope they are ok.

Comment: So the original question was actually quadratic, but I simply substitued each $x_i^2$ to be $x_i$ believing this to not make a difference, which I realise now was a mistake. I have since edited this, but my question remains the same. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: The partial derivative with respect to $\lambda$ is incorrect. That might help.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Sergio! I have since fixed it, but I still do not know how to proceed past that point.

Comment: I think you did fine.

Comment: You said, "simply let $\lambda =−c_{j}$, which forces $_=0$ for $ \not= $". I don't get how one could show this.

Answer (score 1):

Letting $e = (1,1,1, \cdots ,1)^{T},$ by the KKT conditions for the maximization problem in the linear version:
$$\begin{align}
c+\lambda e+\mu = &\  0, \tag{stationarity}\\
\mu \geq 0 \text{ and } \lambda \in &\  \mathbb{R}\tag{dual feasibility}\\
x^{T} \mu = &\ 0, \tag{complementary slackness} \\
x^{T} e = 1, \text{and } x \geq & \ 0 \tag{primal feasibility},
\end{align}$$

Letting $x_i>0$, by the complementary slackness, $\mu_i = 0$, and, by and stationarity condition, thus
$$ \lambda + c_i = 0. $$ This means that $c-c_i e=-\mu \leq 0.$ Hence, $$c_j \leq c_i,$$ for all $j.$ Thus, $\max_{j=1,\cdots, n}\{c_j\} \leq c_i \leq  \max_{j=1,\cdots, n}\{c_j\} $. This means, $c_i= \max_{j=1,\cdots, n}\{c_j\}.$

To conclude, any $x$ with $e^{T}x = 1$ and $x \geq 0$, satisfying that, if $$c_i -  \max_{j=1,\cdots, n}\{c_j\}<0,$$ we have $x_i=0,$ is a solution, since any of such $x'$s satisfies the KKT conditions for a linear programming problem. That's the solution set (necessarily not empty, since you found a solution).