# The steepest descent direction constrained to non-negative variables

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, subgradient

Recently, another user asked about the steepest descent direction constrained to non-negative variables, but using the $L_1$ norm to avoid null directions, see this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4569202/simple-lagrange-multiplier-question/4572365#4572365). His ideas led to the following optimization problem:
$$
\begin{align} \tag{*}
\min_{d \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} &\  c^{T} d \\
\text{subject to } & \text{e}^{T} d = 1 \\
& d\geq 0,
\end{align}
$$ in which $\text{e} = (1,1,1, \cdots ,1)^{T}.$ However, this direction of descent might be thought as not a good one, since it tends to look for directions whose coordinates are sparse. Hence, if one wants to minimize in the positive octant using a descent algorithm, it would be preferable to look for non-zero descent directions whose Euclidean norm is 1. That is, instead of looking for directions of  (*), one should look for directions $d$ solving the problem
$$
\begin{align} \tag{**}
\min_{d \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} &\  c^{T} d \\
\text{subject to } & \dfrac{1}{2}\|d\|^2_{2} = \dfrac{1}{2} \\
& d\geq 0,
\end{align}
$$
where $\| \|_2$ means the Euclidean norm. The question is:

> What are the directions $d$ which solves the problem (**)?

It does not seem hard to find good candidates for minimizers, but it does not seem trivial also -- after some thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Non-Negative Least-Squares problem is
$$\min_x\;\|Ax-b\|^2_2 \qquad{\rm s.t.}\;\;x_k\ge 0$$
Remapping the variables to
$\;\left(A=c^T,\;b=[\,{\tt1}\,],\;x=d\,\right)\;$ recovers the initial problem.

The standard solver for this problem is Matlab's `lsqnonneg` which has been ported to many other languages (R, Octave, Scilab, Julia, etc).

An algorithm for very large problems is described in [this paper](https://optimization-online.org/2010/05/2629/) by Dhillon, Kim & Sra.

Another possibility is the [Sequential Coordinate-wise](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/ftp/articles/franc/Franc-TR-2005-06.pdf) algorithm by Frank, Navara & Hlavac.

Comment: This is quite interesting. I was not aware of the Non-negative least squares class of problems. I thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Yes, NNLS is quite a workhorse. For example, Quadratic Programming (QP) problems can be [reformulated and solved](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7163541) via NNLS algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of $c\geq 0$, the solution is relatively easy. Any normalized vector $d$ such that $c^{T}d=0$ and $d\geq 0$ solves the problem.

In the case in which, for some $i$, $c_i<0$, we need the KKT conditions. First, It is not hard to find that every feasible point of (**) satisfies a constraint qualification, for example, the LICQ conditions. Hence, every minimizer satisfies the KKT conditions. This way, we can write the KKT conditions for a minimizer of $(**)$ as
$$\begin{align}
c-\lambda x-\mu = &\  0, \tag{stationarity}\\
\mu \geq 0 \text{ and } \lambda \in &\  \mathbb{R}\tag{dual feasibility}\\
x^{T} \mu = &\ 0, \tag{complementary slackness} \\
\|x\|_2^2 = 1, \text{and } x \geq & \ 0 \tag{primal feasibility},
\end{align}$$

Multiplying the stationarity condition by $x^{T}$ on the left, we have $c^T x- \lambda = 0.$ Thus $c^{T} x =\lambda.$

On the other hand, letting $x_j>0$, by the complementary slackness, $\mu_j = 0$, and, by the stationarity condition,
$$ c_j = c^{T} x\ x_j \tag{***}.$$ On the other hand, since $c^{T} x \leq c^{T} e_i = c_i<0$. This means, by (***), $c_j<0$ whenever $x_i>0.$  Also, note that it can't be $c_j<0$ and $x_j=0$ by the stationarity condition. Otherwise, $\mu_i<0$. Hence, $$c_j<0 \text{ if and only if } x_j>0.$$

Also, we have that, multiplying (***) by $c_j$ and summing the things up, we have $\sum_{x_j>0} c_j^2 = (c^{T} x)^2$. Consequently, again by (***), $$
x_j = \left\lbrace \begin{align}
 - \dfrac{c_j}{\sqrt{\sum_{x_j>0}c_j^2}}, & \text{ if } x_i>0\\
 0, & \text{ if } x_j=0.
\end{align}\right. $$  Combining all the results, this vector can be rewritten as  $$x = - \dfrac{c_{(-)}}{{\|c_{(-)}\|_{2}}},$$ where $c_{(-)} = (\text{min}\{c_1,0\}, \text{min}\{c_2,0\}, \text{min}\{c_3,0\}, \cdots, \text{min}\{c_n,0\})$.

> P.S.: It was left the subtle case in which $c>0$, since $c^{T}d=0$ and $d\geq 0$, implies $d=0$ in this case. Similarly to what we have done, it's not hard to prove that $c^{T}x = \sqrt{\sum_{x_j>0}c_j^2}>0$, for every global minimizer $x$. Since the global minimizer is the one which minimizes $\sqrt{\sum_{x_j>0}c_j^2}$ for all possible $x$, the solution is $$x=\text{e}_{\ell},$$ where $\ell \in \text{argmin}\{c_j\}$ and $e_\ell=(0,0,0,\cdots, 1, \cdots 0)$ -- the $1$ is in the $\ell$-th coordinate.